# How to parse and find the node in which the invalid characters are present in xml?

Tags: xml, ora-31011

I have a xml with some invalid characters in the node like 11 (`U+000`) or vertical tab character. When I am trying to insert this xml in to Oracle, I get the exception like:

```
ORA-31011: XML parsing failed
ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing
LPX-00217: invalid character 11 (U+000
```

Hence I need to parse the xml and detect which node contains this invalid character and wrap it inside `cdata` section.

Comment: If it has invalid characters in it, it's *not* XML, and you can't treat it as such. You need to clean it up first.

Comment: We are using a cms where editors accidently copy some illegal characters that has got transformed to xml by the cms. so after that only, we need to parse this xml and wrap the data inside cdata.

Comment: CDATA will not let you include characters that aren't allowed by [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#charsets).

Answer (score 0):

If you can manipulate the XML in a file, an editor like vi can be very useful in finding and removing embedded control characters.  I just processed a 200MB XML file exported from mySQL that included four embedded Ctrl-K (U+000B) characters.  Editing the file with vi and using `:%s/^K//g` allowed me to quickly remove them and move forward.  (Note: If you're not used to using vi, the ^K in the command above was produced by pressing Ctrl-V then Ctrl-K.  Do not just type carat (^) then K -- that won't work.)  And if you're on Windows (like I am), Cygwin is a very handy set of utilities that includes vi.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an ability to use any programming language before you insert XML data into Oracle? You may check that all characters are XML-valid with using [XmlConvert.IsXmlChar Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlconvert.isxmlchar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

C# sample:

```
public static bool CheckValidXmlChars(string content)
{
   return content.All(ch => System.Xml.XmlConvert.IsXmlChar(ch));
}
```

.Net Fiddle - https://dotnetfiddle.net/v1TNus